# How To Decrypt ASP.NET Cookie for CookieAuthentication Middleware

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin

I want Decrypt the OWIN cookie named by default ".AspNet.Cookies" by the CookieAuthentication middleware.

Comment: Sorry I didn't elaborate in the question since I added what I tried in my own answer.

Comment: Have been researching this topic for a few days and found the answer joining together many sources. Just wanted to share the findings. :)

Answer (score 2):

See this link: https://lbadri.wordpress.com/2014/11/23/reading-katana-cookie-authentication-middlewares-cookie-from-formsauthenticationmodule/

```
// Get Cookie
var request = HttpContext.Request;
var cookie = request.Cookies.Get(".AspNet.Cookies");
var ticket = cookie.Value;

// Format Cookie to be converted
ticket = ticket.Replace('-', '+').Replace('_', '/');
var padding = 3 - ((ticket.Length + 3) % 4);
if (padding != 0)
    ticket = ticket + new string('=', padding);
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(ticket);

// Decrypt
bytes = System.Web.Security.MachineKey.Unprotect(bytes,
    typeof(CookieAuthenticationMiddleware).FullName,
    "Cookies", // See below
    "v1");
```

The parameters passed to Unprotect after the *bytes* parameter, are called the **Purposes**, which need to match the expected one in order to be able to decrypt correctly. Otherwise you get **CryptographicException**.

The "Cookies" parameter matches the value in:

```
(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()).AuthenticationType
```

After the decryption you can build the ClaimsIdentity as explained in the link above or dump the bytes to a string.